# Does Wrapped C++ code with java runnable on all OS?

Tags: java, c++, c, swig

I have a question about C/C++ codes, If they are wrapped with Java and run it as a Java Applet in this case could it run on any OS or just the OS it made for?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the degree to which the C++ code is portable, but in any event the C++ code won't run on different platforms without some work - you have to build a platform-specific version of the native code for each target platform.

The Java code does not have this problem because the JVM shields you from (most) platform dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are referring to the use of JNI from Java.  In that case, yes, the C/C++ code has already been compiled and thus runs only on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you'd have to re-compile it for the target platform.

As to how much work that'll take, it'll depend on how carefully you've written the code to be portable -- code written in C or C++ can run the entire gamut from thoroughly portable to *completely* non-portable, or anywhere in between. Using it from Java/JNI doesn't change that.